# Add terminator string with dlmwrite

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

I have write this:

```
dlmwrite(fName,IND,'-append',...  %// Print the matrix
     'delimiter','\n', 'newline','pc');
```

The output is this:

```
23 46 56 67
```

How should I modify the dlmwrite function to have an output like this:

```
23, 46, 56, 67;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `'\n'` as a delimiter?  You should be using `','` instead (which is default, by the way, so you don't have to modify the `'delimiter'` attribute at all in this case).

If you want to use a modified delimiter and a semi-colon to terminate each line, it's a bit of a problem for `dlmwrite`, so use the more powerful `fprintf` instead:

```
fid = fopen(fName, 'a');
fprintf(fid, [repmat('%d, ', 1, size(IND, 2) - 1), '%d;\r\n'], IND.');
fclose(fid);
```

**EDIT**:
Your question is a bit unclear about the desired output, so here are two more options for you:

- If you want to write your data as one long line, instead of `size(IND, 2)` pass `numel(IND)`:

  ```
  fprintf(fid, [repmat('%d, ', 1, numel(IND) - 1), '%d;\r\n'], IND.');
  ```

  or use the following three-liner instead:

  ```
  X = IND.';
  fprintf(fid, '%d, ', X(1:end - 1));
  fprintf(fid, '%d;\r\n', X(end));
  ```
- If you want to serialize your matrix column-wise, don't transpose `IND`:

  ```
  fprintf(fid, [repmat('%d, ', 1, size(IND, 2) - 1), '%d;\r\n'], IND);
  ```

Comment: <code>fprintf(fid, [repmat('%d, ', 1, numel(IND) - 1), '%d;\r\n'], IND.')<code>.This was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You can use backticks (`) around your code block or indent the code by 4 spaces (the latter doesn't work in comments).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the arguments `'delimiter', ', ', 'newline', ';\r\n'`

That works in Octave; it is not clear from the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) that the Matlab version accepts values for 'newline' other than 'pc' and 'unix'.

Comment: In both answers I get the same error:Newline must be either 'pc' or 'unix'.

Comment: In any case: i want that all matrix elements be delimited by "," and after the last matrix element to put ";". It is a .coe file format that i need in my project.

Comment: so , in my file i want to see element_1,element_2,element_3,.......,element_m*n;                         where m-is the number of columns and n-is the number of lines

Comment: and a last obs: the matrix presented is an example, in my project I have a 204x204 matrix

Comment: If the 'newline' value for dlmwrite only accepts 'pc' or 'unix', then it looks like you can't use dlmwrite.  See @EitanT's answer for an alternative.

Comment: I looked at your example: i don't want a ";" after every row.I want all the matrix elements as a vector separated by "," and at the end a ";"